# Write byte[] in a column of RMS

Tags: java, java-me, arrays, rms

Is it possible to write a byte[] in a column of RecordStore? For example I want to write a record which consists of byte[] in first column, String in second column and int in third column.

```
public void writeToRms(byte[] byteArray){
    RecordStore recordStore = RecordStore.openRecordStore("My recordStore", true);
    try{
        byte[] outputRecord;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        // i want to write the parameter **byteArray** here. What method should I use?
        dos.writeUTF("Name");
        dos.writeInt(ctr);
        dos.flush();
        outputRecord = baos.toByteArray();
        recordStore.addRecord(outputRecord, 0, outputRecord.length);
        recordStore.closeRecordStore();
        baos.reset();
        baos.close();
        dos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  The basic code to write out the `byte[]` is this:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);

    // i want to write **byteArray** here. What method should I use?
    dos.writeShort(byteArray.length);
    dos.write(byteArray);

    dos.writeUTF("Name");
    dos.writeInt(ctr);
    dos.flush();
    outputRecord = baos.toByteArray();
```

and then when you read them back in again, you must first read the length of the array, and then the array.  Like this:

```
    RecordStore recordStore = RecordStore.openRecordStore("My recordStore", false);
    RecordEnumeration records = recordStore.enumerateRecords(null, null, true);
    while (records.hasNextElement()) {
       byte[] recordData = records.nextRecord();

       ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(recordData);
       DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bais);

       short arrayLength = dis.readShort();
       byte[] bytes = new byte[arrayLength];
       dis.read(bytes, 0, arrayLength);
```

I think there's a [good RMS example from BlackBerry here](https://github.com/blackberry/JDE-Samples/tree/master/com/rim/samples/device/rmsdemo) ... take a look at `CD.java`.  I know this is a general J2ME question, but I don't think BlackBerry used any RIM-specific libraries here ... it's just standard J2ME.

**Note:** this general technique works with any kind of array, not just `byte[]`.  In order to save it to the record store, you first write out a `short`, indicating how long the array is, and then you write out the array itself.  When you read it back in, you first read a short value, telling you how many array elements to expect, and then you read in the array, knowing how long it should be.

This is actually how RMS itself reads and write strings, using `readUTF()` and `writeUTF()`.  It writes a 2-byte `short` value indicating the string length, and then the array of chars.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my question, I was talking about to write the parameter byteArray(which is a byte[]) to the Rms as one of the column.

Comment: That's what I showed you.  You changed the **name** of the parameter from `myRecord` to `byteArray`.  That doesn't really change the solution.

Comment: I changed the name to make it more understandable. I'm sorry, I thought you read my question wrong just like the other guy who tried to answer my question yesterday.

Comment: Hey sir Nate I found another solution and I'm going to post it here, what do you think is the more optimized solution?

Comment: My solution is definitely better.  First of all, it uses only **two** lines of code (in addition to what you already had in your question).  You write a 2-byte length (`short`).  Then you write the `byte[]`.  That's it.  In the other solution you posted, you still have the extra 2 bytes to write out, specifying the length of the `String` (that's how `writeUTF(String)` works ... it writes out 2 bytes specifying how long the string is).  The other solution also adds `byte[]` to `String` encoding, which provides no value, and just takes more CPU processing.  There's no need to do that.

Comment: Thank you sir Nate for your useful explanation.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'll also note that record store space is limited.  The other problem with base64 encoding the byte[] is that it will get **longer**.  So, if you have a number of these records, the other method will take up more space in your RMS store.  I didn't have room to put that in my last comment ... not enough space :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it, another solution. If I want to write `byte[]` in one of the column of RMS all I need to do is encode first the `byte[]` to a string. [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) specifically then write the `String` to the RMS.

```
public void writeToRms(byte[] byteArray){
    RecordStore recordStore = RecordStore.openRecordStore("My recordStore", true);
    try{
        byte[] outputRecord;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        String encoded = Base64.encode(byteArray);
        dos.writeUTF(encoded);
        dos.writeUTF("Name");
        dos.writeInt(ctr);
        dos.flush();
        outputRecord = baos.toByteArray();
        recordStore.addRecord(outputRecord, 0, outputRecord.length);
        recordStore.closeRecordStore();
        baos.reset();
        baos.close();
        dos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

And when I retrieve it I just need to decode the encoded `String` back to `byte[]`.

Comment: This will work correctly, but as I said in my other comment, there's no need to perform byte[] to String encoding.